# self joined group by issue?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, self-join

I have a problem with a self joined table where the group by isn't working properly or something is wrong with my code.

I'm trying to produce a table where I have housing sales data and I want a result to grouped by area, and housing type.

Here is what I have so far and it is close to what I need.

```
SELECT A1.AREA AREA,
    TRUNC((A1.SOLD_PRICE/A1.ASK_PRICE*100), 2) || '%' "ATT / ROW / TWNHOUSE",
    TRUNC((A2.SOLD_PRICE/A2.ASK_PRICE*100), 2) || '%' "DETACHED",
    TRUNC((A3.SOLD_PRICE/A3.ASK_PRICE*100), 2) || '%' "SEMI-DETACHED"  
FROM SALESRECORDS A1, SALESRECORDS A2, SALESRECORDS A3
WHERE A1.AREA = A2.AREA AND A1.AREA = A3.AREA
GROUP BY A1.AREA, A1.HOUSE_TYPE;
```

This gives me error `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`.

When  I follow the SQL rules, and I add all the items to the group by clause, I get a result similar to the order by statement....

```
SELECT A1.AREA,
    TRUNC((A1.SOLD_PRICE/A1.ASK_PRICE*100), 2) || '%' "ATT / ROW / TWNHOUSE",
    TRUNC((A2.SOLD_PRICE/A2.ASK_PRICE*100), 2) || '%' "DETACHED", 
    TRUNC((A3.SOLD_PRICE/A3.ASK_PRICE*100), 2) || '%' "SEMI-DETACHED"  
FROM SALESRECORDS A1, SALESRECORDS A2, SALESRECORDS A3
WHERE A1.AREA = A2.AREA AND A1.AREA = A3.AREA
GROUP BY A1.AREA, A1.SOLD_PRICE, A1.ASK_PRICE, A2.SOLD_PRICE, A2.ASK_PRICE,
    A3.SOLD_PRICE, A3.ASK_PRICE;
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong....?

Comment: Why do you think you need a group by?  What results are you getting back from the 2nd statement?  What results would you like to be getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** *Edited based on additional information. Also fixed mismatched parentheses in my original answer.*

The requested output looks something like this:

```
Area  Att/Row/Twnhouse  Detached  Semi-Detached
----  ----------------  --------  -------------
East  20.00%            33.33%    75.12%
West  22.22%            44.44%    55.10%
```

If you need an overall percentage for a group, the only safe way to do that is to calculate the total "sell price" and the total "ask price" first, then do the math on the totals. For that you need a subquery to sum everything up. The outer query can then do the math.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT
  Area "Area",
  ROUND(TownhouseSold / TownhouseAsk * 100, 2) || '%' "Att/Row/Twnhouse",
  ROUND(DetachedSold / DetachedAsk * 100, 2) || '%' "Detached",
  ROUND(SemiDetachedSold / SemiDetachedAsk * 100, 2) || '%' "Semi-Detached"
FROM (
  SELECT
    Area,
    SUM(CASE WHEN House_Type = 'Att/Row/Twnhouse' THEN Sold_Price END) AS TownhouseSold,
    SUM(CASE WHEN House_Type = 'Att/Row/Twnhouse' THEN Ask_Price END) AS TownhouseAsk,
    SUM(CASE WHEN House_Type = 'Detached' THEN Sold_Price END) AS DetachedSold,
    SUM(CASE WHEN House_Type = 'Detached' THEN Ask_Price END) AS DetachedAsk,
    SUM(CASE WHEN House_Type = 'Semi-Detached' THEN Sold_Price END) AS SemiDetachedSold,
    SUM(CASE WHEN House_Type = 'Semi-Detached' THEN Ask_Price END) AS SemiDetachedAsk
  FROM SalesRecords
  GROUP BY Area
)
ORDER BY Area
```

---

**Addendum** question restated as "percentage of houses sold for more than the asking price, by area".

The approach is to count (a) number of houses and (b) number that sold above asking price, and group by area. That's the inner query. It also pivots by house type. The outer query calculates the percentages. Here it is:

```
SELECT
  Area "Area",
  ROUND(TownhouseOverAsk / TownhouseCount * 100, 2) || '%' "Att/Row/Twnhouse",
  ROUND(DetachedOverAsk / DetachedCount * 100, 2) || '%' "Detached",
  ROUND(SemiDetachedOverAsk / SemiDetachedCount * 100, 2) || '%' "Semi-Detached"
FROM (
  SELECT
    Area,
    SUM(CASE WHEN House_Type = 'Att/Row/Twnhouse' THEN 1 END) AS TownhouseCount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN House_Type = 'Att/Row/Twnhouse' AND Sold_Price > Ask_Price THEN 1 END) AS TownHouseOverAsk,
    SUM(CASE WHEN House_Type = 'Detached' THEN 1 END) AS DetachedCount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN House_Type = 'Detached' AND Sold_Price > Ask_Price THEN 1 END) AS DetachedOverAsk,
    SUM(CASE WHEN House_Type = 'Semi-Detached' THEN 1 END) AS SemiDetachedCount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN House_Type = 'Semi-Detached' AND Sold_Price > Ask_Price THEN 1 END) AS SemiDetachedOverAsk,
  FROM SalesRecords
  GROUP BY Area
)
ORDER BY Area
```

Comment: No problem, but what do you want the results to look like? If my assumption above isn't correct could you edit your question and add an example of expected output? Also, do you really want to truncate percentages? In cases like this, rounding is generally more appropriate.

Comment: Oops - sorry; I didn't get the sites.google.com link at first. Now I see. I'll take a quick look.

Comment: OK; answer updated. I couldn't read the Oracle table contents screen shot (`Java Printing.pdf` document) because it was too small and it blurred when I tried to enlarge it, so I couldn't make much out of the information there. The expected results document ('the goal.jpg`) was clear though. The query above will get you very close, if not all the way there.

Comment: This is close, but I'm looking for the percentage difference.... IE, I have 9 detached houses in area c14, and I want the percentage of the different. say only 2 sold above the asking price, 2/9*100 =22% the data can be found here https://sites.google.com/site/smithelobe/  it is more of a count than a sum..

Comment: Tom - see the end of the answer; I've added another query with a bit of explanation. It's untested but it should at least be close. Good luck!

Comment: Awsome, Thanks Ed... I tried to do something simular, but kept getting divider by zero error....

Comment: Tom - glad it worked out; this has been an interesting question! I avoided the divide by zero by summing `CASE WHEN whatever THEN 1 END`. That will give you a null if nothing's found, and Oracle just kinda ignores it when you divide. If you do it as `CASE WHEN whatever THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` then you end up with a zero and its accompanying complications.